# Laravel - Displaying Selected ID in a column in database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin, eloquent

I want to select the selected id or data in my database in a column on my edit page. How can I do it? So far, I have done this code but it is giving me an error.

***This is my controller***

```
 public function index($id)
{
    $setting = Setting::find($id);
    return view('admin.settings.edit', compact('setting'));
}
```

***This is my view***

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['Admin\SettingsController@update', $setting->id], 'method' => 'POST']) !!}

        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 ">
            {{Form::label('air_code', 'Airline Code')}}<br>
            {{Form::text('air_code', $setting->settings_code[1], ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter Air Code', 'id'=>'aircode','disabled'])}}
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 ">
            {{Form::label('Flight_No', 'Flight No.')}}<br>
            {{Form::text('Flight_No', $setting->settings_code[2], ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter a Flight Number', 'id'=>'flightno','disabled'])}}
        </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

What I have in my one column settings_code

**[1]FLIGHT_NO, [2]AILINE_NAME**

My error is :

> Too few arguments to function  SettingsController::index(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected

Comment: Can you please show us your routes?

Comment: have you checked what is inside `$setting`?

Answer (score 0):

Not really a Laravel user but I think you need to pre-define that $id with something default it to null then call Setting::find() if there is a valid value on the variable.

Comment: did not work it has an error saying `Trying to get property 'id' of non-object `

Answer (score 0):

if i understand the problem correctly:
if the value is separated by comma, try this:

```
@php
   $settings_code = explode(",", $setting->settings_code);
@endphp

 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 ">
  {{Form::label('air_code', 'Airline Code')}}<br>
  {{Form::text('air_code', $settings_code[0], ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter Air Code', 'id'=>'aircode','disabled'])}}
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 ">
  {{Form::label('Flight_No', 'Flight No.')}}<br>
  {{Form::text('Flight_No', $settings_code[1], ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter a Flight Number', 'id'=>'flightno','disabled'])}}
 </div>
```

though i still find it weird having this two values on a same cell.

Comment: hi @kapitan , no it is not in the same column. but what i need is to call the value on each textbox not on the same databae

Comment: for example i have 5 values on my field so they have id's 1 to 5 . so i need to call each of the value on the textbox

Comment: bro, please see this and answer thanks [see this new link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53735097/laravel-update-values-on-table)