# Laravel - Update values on Table

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Hello how could i update my data on a table? using also a foreach loop to get all data. help thanks

right now my code is giving me an error here is my error

> Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\Admin\SettingsController::index(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected

my ***index.php , table***

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['Admin\SettingsController@update', $setting->id], 'method' => 'POST']) !!}

 <tbody>
                @foreach ($settings as $setting)
                <tr>
                    <td> {{Form::text('settings_code', $setting->settings_code, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter a Flight Number'])}}</td>
                    <td>{{ $setting->subject }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $setting->description }}</td>
                    <td>

                    {{Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT')}}

                    {{Form::submit('Update', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary', 
                    'name'=>'submit'])}} <br><br>
                    </td>
                    </tr>      


        @endforeach

 </tbody>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

my ***Controller***

```
  public function index()
{
    $settings = Setting::where('settings_code', '<>', 'SESSION_VALIDITY')->get();
    $setting = Setting::find($id);
    $setting->settings_code = $request->input('settings_code');
    $setting->save();
    return view('admin.settings.index', compact('settings'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function index(Request $request,$id)
{
$settings = Setting::where('settings_code', '<>', 'SESSION_VALIDITY')->get();
$setting = Setting::find($id);
$setting->settings_code = $request->input('settings_code');
$setting->save();
return view('admin.settings.index', compact('settings'));
}
```